# Install .NET 4.6.1 remotely via powershell

Tags: powershell, remote, .net

I am trying to remotely install .NET framework4.6.1 on a large group of machines. I'm using powershell to remotely script this. The problem is that for whatever reason the .exe does not seem to want to be invoked remotely. I am assuming this is due to the fact that the .exe for the upgrade launches a UI session. However, even passing the "/q" parameter which should allow the install to take place remotely, it still doesn't work. I don't get any errors, and when RDP'd into the machine in question it doesn't appear to be upgrading or using any CPU for the upgrade.

My Script:

```
        Write-Host "Executing 'Upgrade dotnet 4.6' for $server"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
        $Url = 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
        $Exe = "net461.exe"
        $Dest = "C:\\" + $Exe
        $Params = " /q"
        $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
        $client.DownloadFile($Url,$Dest) 
        Invoke-Expression ("cmd.exe /C " + $Dest + $Params)
        }
```

I've also tried using chocolatey and it doesn't work either, for I think the same reasons. running chocolatey locally works.

Comment: Does it work if UAC is disabled on the remote/target computer?

Comment: When automating, I usually cache downloaded files somewhere within my administrative domain whenever possible.  What you're doing is a time bomb that will explode when/if MS reorganizes their site or that URL rots otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that powershell has a default remote shell memory limit of 150MB. The install of .NET 4.6.1 would load the self-extracting exe's contents into memory, some items which were > 150 MB. This link provided the correct method to increase the memory limit.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That executable from MS appears to just be a self extracting archive (I was able to open it with 7-Zip).  Have you tried unzipping the .exe somewhere and then attempting the `/q` switch on the `Setup.exe` contained within?

Comment: I think that's a good idea, believe in doing that for a similar .net runtime install.